# How to pick Hamming distance

Tags: coding-theory, error-correcting-codes, hamming-code

Wikipedia's article [Cyclic redundancy check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) states that for the same n (bits) there are multiple CRCs possible with different polynomial. Then it lists this [Best CRC Polynomials](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/) article that gives some variations with different polynomials. I am looking to implement a simple CRC-8. What should be my criteria for picking one polynomial over another?

I assume that it boils down to selecting the Hamming distance, but how is that related to my problem at hand? How do I pick the correct/best Hamming distance for best detecting possible errors in my case (and in what terms should I describe my case)? For example, will the choice depend on the media for storing/transmitting data or other physical factors or something else?

Comment: Have you read this report, by the same author? http://www.tc.faa.gov/its/worldpac/techrpt/tc14-49.pdf

Comment: No, thanks, that's what I was looking for (at the top of page C-19)! Please post it as an answer and I will be happy to accept it. I only wonder why the "best" polynomials listed at the bottom of page C-18 differ from those listed on https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the list that you mention has written a [thorough report](http://www.tc.faa.gov/its/worldpac/techrpt/tc14-49.pdf) on the problem of selecting a CRC polynomial, which probably contains the answers to all your questions. See page C-19:

> Important to select CRC polynomial based on:
>
> - Data Word length
> - Desired HD
> - Desired CRC size
>
> Safety-critical applications commonly select HD=6 at max message length

For example, HD-6 detects between 1-6 error bits in the Data Word, so the bigger the HD the better (for the given Data Word length).